# How can I initialize the union in const struct?

Tags: c++

```
 const struct EbmlSyntax {
    uint32_t id;
    EbmlType type;
    int list_elem_size;
    int data_offset;
    union {
        uint64_t    u;
        double      f;
        const char *s;
        const struct EbmlSyntax *n;
    } def;
} ;
```

I have to use the const struct above and want to create a a constant struct using

`{ EBML_ID_DOCTYPE,                EBML_STR,  0, offsetof(Ebml,doctype), {.def.s = "(none)"} }`

But, the VS8.0 compiler gives an error error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '.' when I compiler the C++ project.

I have tried several methods ,but, I only find the way that cast the char * to uint64_t(assign to the first type),

```
(uint64_t)("none")
```

and I can use the union. Is this method safe? I check the structure of this and other struct-union object using VS debug tools.It seems OK that the member of struct and union can correctly expained.

Comment: I think the `.` in front of `def.s` should be removed

Comment: C++ does not have designators (the `.def.s =` notation). C does but only since C99, which Microsoft does not support.

Comment: Yes,you are right. I have tried several method ,but, I only find the way that cast the char * to uint64_t, and I can use the union. Is this method safe? It seems OK.

Comment: Strictly, it's not safe, but it should be fine for real use, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can only initialize the first element of the union with that syntax.
You need another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `struct` a constructor, and do the initialization
there.  Of course, this isn't static initialization, but if the
struct isn't used until you're into `main`, that shouldn't be
a problem.

If you really need static initialization, replace the `union`
with a `struct`.  This will increase the size of your object,
but this shouldn't be a big problem if it is only used for
a few objects with static initialization.